# How do I print hyphens if a variable is empty?

Tags: bash, text-processing, printf

I am collecting windows system information using `wmic` on Linux system. For that purpose, I make various `wmic` calls and their output is stored in some variables. After required data is collected, I `echo` those variables, separated by colons, to a file.

But, the problem arises when a variable stores 'null' value, as it does not display anything but just two successive colons.

How can `printf` be utilized in order to display a 'hyphen' whenever there is a null value stored in a variable?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${var:--}"`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on `var:--` part?

Comment: @MandarShinde: see [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
"${var:-word}"
```

This will substitute the value of the variable `$var` if it is set and not empty and, if not, will substitute with whatever is given by as `word`. For example:

```
$ var=foo
$ echo "${var:-bar}"
foo
$ var=
$ echo "${var:-bar}"
bar
```

So, in your specific case, you can use:

```
echo "${var:--}"
```

Or, the [safer and more portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222):

```
printf '%s\n' "${var:--}"
```

Comment: Actually, with some `echo` implementations, `echo -` outputs an empty line as they use `-` to mark the end of options.